# Uploading Problems with the Arduino Robot: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

Tags: arduino

I started working with the Arduino Robot Control Board a few days ago. I did a few tutorials and everything was fine. I could perfectly upload my programs using the Arduino IDE.

Today, I was working on a project and already did uploading, testing, adjusting, uploading again,... I pressed the Upload button and nothing happened and I got the following error message (with verbose output enabled):

```
Der Sketch verwendet 14960 Bytes (52%) des Programmspeicherplatzes. Das Maximum sind 28672 Bytes.
Globale Variablen verwenden 1539 Bytes (60%) des dynamischen Speichers, 1021 Bytes für lokale Variablen verbleiben. Das Maximum sind 2560 Bytes.
Erzwinge Reset durch öffnen/schließen mit 1200 bps auf dem Port /dev/ttyACM1
Beim Hochladen des Sketches ist ein Fehler aufgetreten
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}
Uploading using selected port: /dev/ttyACM1
/home/lukas/Dokumente/Arduino/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/home/lukas/Dokumente/Arduino/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -P/dev/ttyACM1 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino_build_7255/Interrupts.ino.hex:i

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 06:01:25
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/lukas/Dokumente/Arduino/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/lukas/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM1
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
Found programmer: Id = "�"; type = �
    Software Version = Y.�; Hardware Version = .
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: buffered memory access not supported. Maybe it isn't
a butterfly/AVR109 but a AVR910 device?
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: leave prog mode
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: exit bootloader
```

I did check the connection, made sure, that the USB cable is not broken. I actually can use the IDE to upload programs to the lower Motor Board, so it's not the IDE's fault, I assume. But as I am fairly new to the Arduino World, I am quite clueless now.

I read a lot of forum posts, but I couldn't find a working solution. Similiar problems seem to happen to others as well, but for other Arduino platforms. Those answers did not solve my problem, including the Arduino Forum itself.

I am currently on Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS or Windows 10. The same problem is on both OSes.